# Material design date-picker for angular 2

Tags: angular, datepicker, material-design, angular-material, web-frontend

Is there any resource for material design date picker component in angular 2.I searched a lot but no good results found .

Answer (score 3):

angular 2-material-date-picker is not a good solution in the context of material design , the style is not looks like material design,I think the better option is date-picker from md2.

please install

npm install md2 --save

then import the module in App module

for more reference please go [npm packages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md2) and [Git hub page](https://github.com/Promact/md2/tree/master/src/lib/datepicker)

Answer (score 2):

There is a `date picker` component, should be installed in your **root application folder** using :

> npm install angular2-material-datepicker

and then do your import in your `module` component file and start using it merely.
More details [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-material-datepicker).